# Best practice: Creating ORM objects at runtime by scheme stored in DB

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, orm, runtime

At my current project(huge enterprise system) I'm faced to scenario when "simple" objects like table, reference list are created at runtime via system info stored in the same DB(special sys tables). Users can create those simple objects and relations between them.
The complicated objects are created by developers. For the first case We are using SqlOM, and for the second Linq2Sql. So business logic is a mixture of those concepts(sqlOM+linq2sql).

Now I'm thinking about migration to Entity Framework or another ORM that supports to create concrete objects and mapping at runtime. Does anybody can give me an advice?

Comment: Duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874003/whats-the-best-object-relational-mapping-tool-for-net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout Fluent NHibernate for this sort of scenario. http://fluentnhibernate.org/